# SQL Server: Archiving old data

Tags: sql-server, ssis, archive, linked-server

I have a database that is getting pretty big, but the client is only interested in the last 2 years' data.  But they would like to keep the older data "just-in-case".

Now we would like to archive the data to a different server over a WAN.

My plan is to create a stored proc to:

1. Copy all data from lookup tables, tables containing master data and foreign key tables over to the archive server.
2. Copy data from transactional tables over to the archive DB.
3. Delete transactional data from master db that's older than 2 years.

Although the approach will teoretically meet our needs, the 2 main problems are:

1. Performace: I'm copying the data over via SQL Linked Servers.  Some of the big tables are really slow as it needs to compare which records exist and then update them, and the records that doesn't exists needs to be created. Seems like it will run in 3-4 hours.
2. We need to copy the tables in the correct sequence to prevent foreign key violations, and also the tables that have a relationship to itself (eg. Customers table with a ParentCustomer field), needs to be transferred without the ParentCustomer and then the ParentCustomer needs to be updated to prevent FK violations.  Thus it becomes difficult to auto generate my Insert and Update statements (I would like to auto generate my statements as far as possible).

I just feel there might be a better way of archiving data that I do not yet know about. SSIS might be an option, but not sure if it will prevent my existing challenges. I don't know much about SSIS, so I might need to find some material to study it if that's the way to go.

Comment: A suggestion: Partition the table across multiple spindles or ssd. Keep a sliding window partition with current and historical. Current data will be read from one disk the other from a slower disk.

Comment: I agree - don't assume you need to jump through hoops to archive the data. First investigate partitioning (you can transparently move data to another disk) and clistered columnstore indexes (compress the data and improve performance)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a batch process that will run as a scheduled task; perhaps every night.  There are two options, which you have already discussed:

1) SQL Agent Job, which executes a Stored Procedure.  The stored procedure will use Linked Servers.

2) SQL Agent Job, which will execute an SSIS package.

I believe you could benefit from a combination of both approaches, which would avoid Linked Serverd.  Here are the steps:

1) An SQL Agent Job executes an SSIS package, which transfers the data to be archived from the live database to the copy database.  This should be done in a specific sequence to avoid foreign key violations.

2) Once the SSIS package has executed the transfer, then it executes a stored procedure on the live database deleting the information that is over two years old.  The stored procedure will not require any linked servers.

You will have to use transactions to make sure duplicate data is not archived.  For example, if the SSIS package fails then the transaction should be rolled back and the Stored Procedure should not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [table partitions](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/) to create separate partitions for relevant date ranges.